# Sheldon Axler. Linear Algebra Done Right. 3rd Edition, Chapter 3, Exercises 3A, Problem 13

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I read elsewhere two proofs to the problem below which are quite different from the one that I am posting here. For this reason and because I do not have background in rigorous math, I am not confident that my proof is correct. Could you help me see if there are any mistakes?

**Problem 13**: Suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in $V$. Suppose also that $W\neq\{0\}$. Prove that there exist $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in W$ such that no $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$  satisfies $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1,\ldots,m$.

*Proof*. Suppose, for a contradiction, that for every $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in W$, there exists $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1,\ldots,m$. Suppose also that $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ is a linearly independent list. Since $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1,\ldots,m$, then $Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_m$ is linearly independent. This fact and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ imply that $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ is linearly independent, which contradicts our assumption that $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in $V$. This completes the proof.

Comment: You have only shown that *if* you can find $m$ linearly independent vectors in $W$, then the result holds. But you have not shown that you *can* always find $m$ linearly independent vectors in $W$. So your argument is at best incomplete.

Comment: I messed up my first comment. As @ArturoMagidin points out you do not prove the full result asked. I guess one of the proofs you read is: assume $v_1=\sum_{k=2}^m\lambda_k v_k$ then $T(v_1)=\sum_{k=2}^m\lambda_k T(v_k)$ so it suffices to take $w_1\neq 0$ and all other $w_k=0$ and if for all $k$ $T(v_k)=w_k$, we have the contradiction $0\neq w_1=T(v_1)=\sum_{k=2}^m\lambda_k T(v_k)=0$. In your proof you are taking $W$ "larger" than necessary by using a more-stringent-than-necessary condition on the images $w_i$; for instance for any $V$ and $v_i$, $W$ can have dimension 1.